# Adding Breakpoint to detect iOS 9 Autolayout engine failure

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

How to detect which UI code made this exception "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes. This will cause an exception in a future release.".This happens when UI updation takes place in background thread in iOS 9 and above.

Comment: Check this out https://gist.github.com/steipete/5664345

Answer (score 0):

**Please check below define Method which is related to your UI, Due to this you got above mention error**

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showLoadingView) toTarget:AppDelegate withObject:nil];

-(void)showLoadingView
{
   ...
   [window addSubview:object.view];
   ...
}
```

> Note: In newer version of xcode exclude this functionality

Hope It'll helpful for you.